# For Loop running infinitely

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop

So Ive been fighting  with this for loop for a day and a half now, when I get it to actually print it goes infinitely,  even when the if statement (logCount === 10) is satisfied... 
Not too sure what to try anymore, really feel like its far simpler than what I'm trying....

Any attempts at a solution are appreciated..

```
var timers = [];

var log = (function(outputFunc) {

  var counter = 0;
  var callerLog = [];
  var dateTime = [];

  //assigning current Date to a variable to print for logs
  let logDate = new Date();
  return function(timer) {
    for (var logCount = 0; logCount <= 10; logCount++) {
      //printing data without using printFunc, as specified
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += logCount + " " + timer + " " + logDate + "<br>";

      //TODO: add after for loop is resolved.
      if (logCount >= 10) {
        clearInterval(timer1);
        clearInterval(timer2);
        clearInterval(timer3);
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br><br/> Logging stopped.";
      }
    }
  }
})(printFunc);

function printFunc(output) {
  document.write(output + "<br>");
}

function startMeUp() {
  // add each of the timer references to the timers array
  // as part of invoking the log function following each interval
  timers.push(setInterval("log('Timer1')", 1000));
  timers.push(setInterval("log('Timer2')", 1200));
  timers.push(setInterval("log('Timer3')", 1700));
}
```

Comment: What is the objective of this code?

Comment: why are strings passed to setInterval ?

Comment: The only thing I can see in the code provided here is that the `clearInterval` will never work because `timer1`, `timer2` and `timer3` are never defined. That, and `printFunc` will wipe the entire page, which can cause the `document.getElementById` to start throwing null pointer exceptions. However, the `for` loop should properly terminate after it runs 11 times. If anything, from the code here, I'd expect it to finish even sooner due to an error. Although it might be re-running forever due to the `setInterval`s

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You're passing strings to a setInterval function and there's no declaration of any timers that you're trying to clear.

Comment: My prof gave me this code lmao thanks everyone, was clearly bugged as hell haha all fixed thank you, was literally wasting my time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
function printFunc(output) {
    // Replaced with console.log for my own convenience
    console.log(output);
}

// Not really a factory, just a curry of the outputFunc
function loggerFactory(outputFunc) {
    return function startLogger(name, interval) {
        // Variables to keep track of the iterations and a reference to the interval to cancel
        let logCount = 0;
        let intervalRef;

        function tick() {
            // On each tick, check if we're done
            // If yes, clear the interval and do the last output
            // If no, do some output and increment the iterator
            // Once the next tick passes we'll check again
            // If you were using setTimeout instead you would have to requeue the tick here
            if (logCount >= 10) {
                clearInterval(intervalRef);
                outputFunc('Done ' + name);
            } else {
                outputFunc(logCount + " " + name);
                logCount += 1;
            }
        }

        // Start it of
        intervalRef = setInterval(tick, interval);
    }
}

const logger = loggerFactory(printFunc);

function startMeUp() {
    console.log('Starting');
    logger('Log1', 1000);
    logger('Log2', 1200);
    logger('Log3', 1700);
}
startMeUp();
```

Some notes:
You could push the intervalRefs into an array but I find it nicer to encapsulate that work within the same logger, since it should only clean up itself anyway.

When working with intervals (or asynchronous code in general) for loops are usually not what you're looking for. For loops are inherently synchronous, all iterations will be run directly after each other, without space for anything else. What you were looking for was a way to run multiple asynchronous "tracks" at the same time. You could use a for loop to start these "tracks", such as:

```
 for () {
   logger('Log' + i, 1000 * i);
 }
```

But the key lies in that the logger quickly sets up the interval function and then returns. That way your for loop can quickly "schedule" the tasks but the logger runs the iterations internally asynchronously by using setInterval or setTimeout.

Comment: Appreciate the extra knowledge,  ended up using a do while to complete the lab but always appreciate applicable knowledge thanks 